# HTML & CSS - Text and picture

Tags: html, css

I am writing a simple CV which i am coding into a small web page to display my skills to possible employers. I am only 17 and hoping to get an apprenticeship in web development.

Now, my problem is, I have added an image of myself on the center of the top of the page and i'm trying to wrap my fore and surname on either side of the image. I have used a list for each name and then set their display to inline, and their list-style to none.
[This image is what I am currently at.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uME1r.png)
[This is what I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9jy3.png)

How will I go about doing this? I can provide the code is needed as its a fresh page.

EDIT: Yes, ill align the text properly once completed.

I PUT THE CODE LINKS IN THE IMGUR PICS AS I CANT POST > 2 LINKS.

Comment: You gotta show us some code. And what's the thinking behind using list instead of good old divs, or more semantically, a heading tag?

Comment: okay, ill make a doc now :)

Comment: The standard way around here is to use http://jsfiddle.com/ - just paste your HTML body, JS and CSS into the boxes, and the fourth box will show the output when you click 'Run'. Then click save, and share the link here.

Comment: Try http://jsonresume.org/getting-started/ instead of fiddling.

Comment: @Nooneknows i have, check the links in the post

Comment: Use a `h1` element, wrap each name in `span` within it, position them as you wish and then set your image as a background.

Comment: Please post a complete code example *in your question*. While sites like jsfiddle and jsbin are a great supplement to a question, they should never be the sole source of the code.

Comment: Okay here's a fiddle with your code... http://jsfiddle.net/mg5pg5v1/1/ (added a closing tag)

Comment: @j08691 sorry, i'm new here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the `li` and do it completely in a `div` with `vertical-align:middle;` like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    Kieran<img src="http://i.imgur.com/2cEiTiu.jpg" height="150" width="150" />Rigby
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:80%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
img {
    border-radius:50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:4em;
    padding-right:4em;
}
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/codyogden/9mmteper/

Comment: Note that it would be better to give the `img` an ID instead of just putting the CSS I provided above in your main doc.

Comment: Ahh that's perfect :D Will have to study that up so i can do it in the future. Simple stuff, I know, but we all start somewhere.

Comment: Quick Q. How can I space out the words from the picture? I've tried divs but that messes it all up.

Comment: You can use the `padding-left` & `padding-right` like I used in the CSS for `img` above. That will add space between the image and the text next to it on both sides.

Comment: Done it! But now i can't seem to add the white border around the pic as the border is skewed with the padding

Comment: Okay. Switch to `margin-left` & `margin-right` Cheers!

Comment: Hey, I am wondering whether you can help me center something.
http://jsfiddle.net/c4bxhm6y/
If you make the view larger, you can see how the image isn't the center point, this would be because the extra text ive added. How can i make the image the center point.